# Jquery dialog box close issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery ui dialog box. My question, I want to track the okay button and close dialog  which is the X button on the dialog box separately. If the dialog is closed using X button then the dialog close event  should not occur.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is yet. Is there something you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: please show some code

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS that does not over ride every dialog on the page.

The CSS

```
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display: none }
```

The HTML

```
<div class="selector" title="No close button">
    Dialog box without close button
</div>
```

demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/AGZKF/413/

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery you can try using the beforeClose option!

```
$( "#yourdialog" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just track buttons like this. That way you won't track the X button but just those that you want to.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ 
   buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { 
      //TRACK IT HERE
      $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
   } } ] 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the the dialogclose event

`$( ".dropDownBox" ).on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) {} );`

you can then use the event variable inside the function for finding either it was x or ok button

Comment: $("#dialog").on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) {
     alert('target id = '+event.target.id);    
       alert('type = '+event.type);  }); how do I trace it as both the events gives me similar output target id = dialog and type = dialogclose